# Background-size CSS3 query

Tags: css

I'm currently using the background-size property in CSS. I have it set to 100%, however I would like it so that if the div reached a minimum height of 800px for it to stop resizing down....is there anyway I can force this?

Thanks in advance!

```
#test-bg {
   background:url('../images/test_bg.jpg') 0 0 no-repeat;
   background-size:100%;
   width:100%;
   height:1900px;
   min-height:800px;
   position:absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it by applying a min width! Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

In CSS2, you get the option of specifying the `min-height`.

Take a look at the link below and see if it helps you:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp

Comment: I have a min-height but it's disreguarded :-/

Comment: (I think someone will come along and provide a better answer, but here goes) Maybe you can try nested div? so the inner div have the background-size as 100%, outer diff will have the min-height.